# How to make TypeScript understand type checking?

Tags: typescript

I have a function dynamically obtaining a value of an object's property in TypeScript.
The property can be of type `number` or `Color`.
If the property is of type `number` the function returns the property's value, else it returns the array created from the property (in this case from `Color` = [R,G,B]).

```js
class Color {
  r: number
  g: number
  b: number
  constructor( r: number, g: number, b: number ) {
    this.r = r;
    this.g = g;
    this.b = b;
  }

  toArray() {
    const array = [0, 0, 0];
    array[0] = this.r;
    array[1] = this.g;
    array[2] = this.b;

    return array;
  }
}

interface MyObject {
   intensity: number, // float number
   color: Color,
                
}

type ObjectProperty = 'intensity'|'color'

const myFunc = (obj: MyObject, property: ObjectProperty): number|number[] => {
   if (typeof obj[property] === 'number') {
      return obj[property] // TS error 2)
   } else {
      return obj[property].toArray() //TS error 1)
   }
}
```

`myFunc` throws TS errors: 1)

```
TS2339: Property 'toArray' does not exist on type 'number | Color'.   Property 'toArray' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

and 2)

```
TS2322: Type 'number | Color' is not assignable to type 'number | number[]'.   Type 'Color' is not assignable to type 'number | number[]'.
```

Is there a way to make TS understand the type check which happened before calling the `toArray()` function and tha fact that `typeof Color !== number`?

Comment: Try by asigning the obj[property] value to a constant

Comment: Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that demonstrates your issue to others when they paste it into their own IDEs.  In particular you should either define `Color` or replace it with something else.  This will make it easier for others to work with and give a testable solution.

Answer (score 1):

The errors are eliminated by assigning the `obj[property]` value to a constant.

```js
const myFunc = (obj: MyObject, property: ObjectProperty): number|number[] => {
  const value = obj[property];
  if (typeof value === 'number') {
    return value
  } else {
    return value.toArray()
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the standard approach, as per [microsoft/TypeScript#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530)

Answer (score 0):

This approach doesn't seem to face any errors...

```
interface MyObject {
   intensity: number, // float number
   color: {toArray():[number,number,number]}, // Color class represents the color in hex and contains toArray() function
                 // toArray() creates [R,G,B] number array
}

type ObjectProperty = 'intensity'|'color'

const myFunc = (obj: MyObject, property: ObjectProperty): number|number[] => {
  if(property === "color"){
    return obj[property].toArray()
  }
  else{
    return obj[property]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but in my code (not the question) the `MyObject` have much more properties and `type Object Property = keyof typeof MyObject`, so there is no other way (except manual key definition) to tell which properties are of which type than using `typeof` with regarding execution.